# UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit is not working in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on the application where the image is to be choose from gallery.

Image that I am going to pick from gallery has size of 50*50.

I am using `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` to  set imageview accroding to image. Though image is being stretch as below image.

[image]

Below is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if (IS_IPHONE_6)
    {
        self.imgViewUserPic.frame=CGRectMake(10, 8, 300, 300);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6_Plus)
    {
        self.imgViewUserPic.frame=CGRectMake(10, 6, 320, 320);

    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_4)
    {
        self.imgViewUserPic.frame=CGRectMake(50, 12, 220, 220);
    }
    else
    {
            self.imgViewUserPic.frame=CGRectMake(50, 12, 220, 220);
     }

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    userImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    NSLog(@"%f %f",userImage.size.width,userImage.size.height);
 // NSData *image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userImage, 0.8);

    self.imgViewUserPic.contentMode =  UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    self.imgViewUserPic.image=userImage;

    NSLog(@"%f %f",_imgViewUserPic.frame.size.width,_imgViewUserPic.frame.size.height);


    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

please help me out.I just ant to resize imageview as image with the help of  `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: one question if what  is your self.imgViewUserPic width and hwight

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated my question.